# Scaling of images for mobile devices in html

Tags: html, mobile

I have an ASP.net web site.

I am displaying images via a timer.

For my mobile version i set this tag:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

For the mobile version I want to resize the image to half its original size to 180x144.

My timer calls an ashx page. This returns a byte stream as that is how my images are stored.

1). Do I have to convert to an image, resize it and convert back as a byte array or is there a different way that is standard practice that I am unaware of?

2). Do I have to set the html image tag width to 100% and let it scale the height? What happens if the mobile device screen is of such specification that the scaling of the height results in the 
image height going off screen?

What are the best practices to use in these case?

Thanks

Comment: You are displaying images via a timer? It sounds like you're really after a responsive design. Are you ok with scaling your mobile images? It's pretty typical to constrain your image dimension with something like `img { max-width:100% }` and feed that to mobile devices via CSS media queries. I really think you are after a CSS solution, not a server-side one.

Comment: HI, thanks for your comments. Yes, I anticipate it being client-side code I need to use.  Just wanted to know best practices. Thanks :)

Comment: There are some solutions out there where the server will determine which size of image to send down the pipe, but we're still a bit in the wild west on that front. The `Picture` HTML element will help once it becomes better supported.